# AJAX: Why does my http.readystate only return 4?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a file folder set up to work with AJAX. I have a dummy json file:

```
{
    "tweets": [
        {
          "content": "hello"  
        },
        {
          "content": "world"  
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem I'm having, is that when I console.log the `http` object, I keep getting a `readystate` of "4". But, I believe I'm supposed to get different ready states. This makes me think my code is wrong.

I'm following along to this video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0ZUpPiV1ac&index=2&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jAhrjtZ9U93UMIhnCc44MH

Can someone explain why I can't seem to get the different ready states?

```
window.onload = function() {


    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();


    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(http);
    }

    http.open('GET', 'data/tweets.json', true);
    http.send();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does the console show and are you sure it's ONLY 4? There are 5 states - 4 being the final state; the first 4 happen almost instantly with a good connection.

> 0      The request is not initialized
>
> 1      The request has been setup
>
> 2      The request has been sent
>
> 3      The request is in process
>
> 4      The request is complete

Comment: In my console.log - if I change it to "console.log(http.readystate)" - i get 1,2,3,4 - However, if I just log "http" - I get 4 "XMLHttpRequest" objects - all of which have a readystate of 4. How does that make sense?

Comment: http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(http);
    }

Comment: So all is working - if you're getting that output in the log, the ready state is changing and firing the function as expected. http is simply your XMLHttpRequest object and onreadystatechange is a function stored on it which fires when the state changes. Are you trying to achieve something in particular?

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the content, which is great. But my console log looks different to the video I'm watching  - even though my code is the same. I'm just wondering why I can't seem to log out the different ready states using the above code

Comment: I see what you're saying now (after rereading your edited first post). As you are using the inspector to review the object, it is updating so it appears incorrect to you. Each one of the console.log() codes is outputting the SAME object so (to your eye) the inspector dynamically updates each of them as the properties change. So just be mindful that, when you click back through them, you are actually exploring the exact same object (with the changed readystate)

Comment: But I thought the purpose of the "onreadystatechange" function was to log out the object at the different points of state change - meaning that you'd get 5 different objects with unique ready states?

Comment: in the link I provided, if you go to: 7:36 of that, you can see what I'm talking about

Comment: Nope - The inspector's purpose is to allow just that - inspection of objects, elements and their properties to assist with debugging. As an object changes, this allows real-time access to it's current properties. If you don't want the inspector to change, you need to output a constant (non-changing) value. This is why when you output it's ready state (sent as a string/constant number) it works - this simply PRINTS the value, not an object.

Comment: Your video may be using a different browser that isn't as intelligent - I think IE will show the value and not change, whereas Chrome dynamically updates.

Comment: In the video, the guy is using Atom and “enable live reload” has that got an impact on that?

Comment: He’s using chrome

Comment: Could be - Don't have it so can't say. I wouldn't be concerned as the inspector is for development purposes only; most of the time your users won't even know it's there. Other than that, there are too many variables to consider - browser, browser version, add-ins etc. So long as your code is running as expected, I wouldn't worry!

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(http.readyState);
```

You can try the code above,it works.The readState vary in 2,3,4.